# Google Foobar Java: LAMB Distribution Test 7 error

Tags: java, algorithm

I have on the first problem of Google Foobar Level 2. The problem is:

Being a henchman isn't all drudgery. Occasionally, when feeling generous, Commander Lambda hand out Lucky LAMBs (Lambda's All-purpose Money Bucks). Henchmen can use Lucky LAMBs to buy things like a second pair of socks, a pillow for their bunks, or even a third daily meal!

However, actually passing out LAMBs isn't easy. Each henchman squad has a strict seniority ranking which must be respected -- or else the henchmen will revolt and you'll all get demoted back to minions again!

There are 4 key rules which you must follow in order to avoid a revolt:
1. The most junior henchman (with the least seniority) gets exactly 1 LAMB.  (There will always be at least 1 henchman on a team.)
2. A henchman will revolt if the person who ranks immediately above them gets more than double the number of LAMBs they do.
3. A henchman will revolt if the amount of LAMBs given to their next two subordinates combined is more than the number of LAMBs they get.  (Note that the two most junior henchmen won't have two subordinates, so this rule doesn't apply to them.  The 2nd most junior henchman would require at least as many LAMBs as the most junior henchman.)
4. You can always find more henchmen to pay - the Commander has plenty of employees.  If there are enough LAMBs left over such that another henchman could be added as the most senior while obeying the other rules, you must always add and pay that henchman.

Note that you may not be able to hand out all the LAMBs. A single LAMB cannot be subdivided. That is, all henchmen must get a positive integer number of LAMBs.

Write a function called solution(total_lambs), where total_lambs is the integer number of LAMBs in the handout you are trying to divide. It should return an integer which represents the difference between the minimum and maximum number of henchmen who can share the LAMBs (that is, being as generous as possible to those you pay and as stingy as possible, respectively) while still obeying all of the above rules to avoid a revolt.  For instance, if you had 10 LAMBs and were as generous as possible, you could only pay 3 henchmen (1, 2, and 4 LAMBs, in order of ascending seniority), whereas if you were as stingy as possible, you could pay 4 henchmen (1, 1, 2, and 3 LAMBs). Therefore, solution(10) should return 4-3 = 1.

To keep things interesting, Commander Lambda varies the sizes of the Lucky LAMB payouts. You can expect total_lambs to always be a positive integer less than 1 billion (10 ^ 9).

My code:

```
public class Solution {
        public static int solution(int total_lambs) {
        // person 1 gets 1 lamb
        // person 2 gets more than 1 lamb
        // person 3 gets more than or = person 1 + person 2  but less or = than double person 2
        // person 4 gets more than person 3 + person 2 but less than or = double person 3


        return (solution_conservative(total_lambs) - solution_generous(total_lambs));

    }
    public static int solution_generous(int total_lambs) {
        int lamb_pay_current = 0;
        int person_before = 0;
        //int person_before_before = 0;
        int person_counter = 0;
        for (int lamb_pay_cumm = 0; lamb_pay_cumm < total_lambs; lamb_pay_cumm += lamb_pay_current) {
            if (!(total_lambs > 0)) {break;}
            if ((total_lambs == 1)) {break;}
            if ((lamb_pay_cumm == 0) && (total_lambs > 0)) {
                lamb_pay_current = 1;
                person_counter++;

                continue;
            }
            if ((lamb_pay_cumm) == 1 && (total_lambs > 1)) {
                lamb_pay_current = 2;
                person_before = 1;
                person_counter++;

                continue;
            }
            if (person_before == 1) {
                person_before = 2;
            }
            if (person_before * 2 + lamb_pay_cumm > total_lambs) {continue;}
            lamb_pay_current = person_before * 2;
            person_counter++;
           // person_before_before = person_before;
            person_before = lamb_pay_current;



        }
        if (total_lambs == 1) {return 1;}
        if (!(total_lambs > 0)) {return 0;}
        return person_counter;
    }
    public static int solution_conservative(int total_lambs) {

        int lamb_pay_current = 0;
        int person_before = 0;
        int person_before_before = 0;
        int person_counter = 0;
        for (int lamb_pay_cumm = 0; lamb_pay_cumm < total_lambs; lamb_pay_cumm += lamb_pay_current) {
            if (!(total_lambs > 0)) {break;}
            if ((total_lambs == 1)) {break;}
            if ((lamb_pay_cumm == 0) && (total_lambs > 0)) {
                lamb_pay_current = 1;
                person_counter++;

                continue;
            }
            if ((lamb_pay_cumm) == 1 && (total_lambs > 1)) {
                lamb_pay_current = 1;
                person_before = 1;
                person_counter++;

                continue;
            }
            if (person_before == 1) {
                person_before_before = 1;
            }
            if (person_before + person_before_before + lamb_pay_cumm > total_lambs) {continue;}
            lamb_pay_current = person_before + person_before_before;
            person_counter++;
            person_before_before = person_before;
            person_before = lamb_pay_current;



        }
        if (total_lambs == 1) {return 1;}
        if (!(total_lambs > 0)) {return 0;}
        return person_counter;
    }
}
```

What I am trying to get done is that I have 2 functions. One is to find the most "generous" possible way to give everyone the most  amount of LAMBS possible before someone revolts. This pattern appears to be like this: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 etc. **I may be wrong**. The other function is to find the most "conservative" possible way to give everyone the **least** amount of LAMBS possible before someone revolts. This pattern appears to be like this: 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, etc. **I may also be wrong**.

Whenever I do
"verify Solutions.java", it always fails Test #7. All other tests succeed, just this one fails. And I don't know what Test #7 is.

i have also tried most of the tests i knew of on Intellij Idea but all of them looked correct to me...

Answer (score 1):

You are right about the patterns of generous and stingy. Generous path follows powers of two and the stingy follows pattern of fibonacci.

It is hard to figure out what is wrong with your code. But I think most probably your code doesn't calculate the number of henchmen correctly especially when there are remaining lambs that can be handed out without violating the restrictions.

- Generous:
  Start with the power of two = 1 and keep taking powers of two and adding to lambs to be paid, until you exceed the total_lambs. When you exceed make sure that you subtract the excess from the paid out lambs, so you get the original lambs paid. Also get the last two paid lambs which can be easily obtained by:

  current_power_of_two/2 + current_power_of_two/4

  See if it is less than or equal to remaining lambs = total_lambs - lambs_paid, then increment the henchmen by 1.
- Stingy: Its the same approach except here you keep track of the last two paid lambs in the fibonacci series.

Here is one straightforward implementation for both generous and stingy handouts:

```
public static int solution_generous(int total_lambs) {
    // Apply power of two

    int power_of_two = 1;
    int henchmen = 1;
    int lambs_paid = 1;
    while ( lambs_paid <= total_lambs ) {
        power_of_two = 2*power_of_two;
        lambs_paid += power_of_two;
        if ( lambs_paid > total_lambs ) {
            lambs_paid -= power_of_two;
            power_of_two = power_of_two/2;
            break;
        }
        henchmen++;
    }
    int last_one = power_of_two;
    int last_before_one = power_of_two/2;
    if ( last_one + last_before_one <= total_lambs - lambs_paid ) {
        henchmen++;
    }
    return henchmen;
}

public static int solution_conservative(int total_lambs) {
    //Fibonacci
    int f1 = 1;
    int f2 = 1;
    int f12 = f1 + f2;
    int henchmen = 1;
    int lambs_paid = f1;
    int last_two_paid = f2;
    while ( lambs_paid <= total_lambs ) {
        last_two_paid = f2;
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f12;
        f12 = f1 + f2;
        lambs_paid += f1;
        if ( lambs_paid > total_lambs ) {
            break;
        }
        henchmen++;
    }
    if ( last_two_paid <= total_lambs - lambs_paid ) {
        henchmen++;
    }
    return henchmen;
}
```

Comment: ummmm... i tested your exact code because when i tried to implement it, it failed test 6.
when i used ur exact code however, it also failed test 6. ??? help please

Comment: try the updated code, it is the order of updating the variables...

Comment: didn't work, still had the same problem. also, i only copied the generous function bc my conservative had to be right... i calculated up to a sum of 1 billion and divided the last 2 terms and was equal to phi up to the 15th digit...

Comment: Curious what happens if you copied both the functions?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, but after copy pasting both functions it still fails Test 6 and 7.
i wonder if it is something related to edge cases and the solution() function not handling them well..

Comment: not sure what's happening looks ok to me. will revisit once I get some time.